# Can I map two XmlElement to the same string?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have an xml string I dynamically create from a spreadsheet.  There are two columns that are frequently mislabeled by users (yes we have a template that the use *most* of the time).

I serialize that string to a custom Object.

I would like to account for the common mistakes.  I have tried the following with my Serializer:

```
[XmlElement("MATTYPE")]
[XmlElement("MATLTYPE")]
public string MATLTYPE { get; set; }
[XmlElement("DEPTID")]
[XmlElement("WORKCENTER")]
public string WORKCENTER { get; set; }
```

Ideally, either `<MATTYPE>` **OR** `<MATLTYPE>` would map to the `MATLTYPE` string.
Same with `<DEPTID>` **OR** `<WORKCENTER>` mapping to `WORKCERNTER`

Both elements will not exist in the same file, but either may.

Can this be done easily?

**UPDATE:**

I have tried this:

```
[XmlElement("MATTYPE")]
public string _Mttype { get; set; }
[XmlElement("MATLTYPE")]
public string _Matltype { get; set; }
public string MATLTYPE { get { return GetMATLTYPE(); } set { matltp = value; } }
public string GetMATLTYPE()
{
    var mistakes = new [] {_Mttype, _Matltype};
    matltp = mistakes.FirstOrDefault(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
    return matltp;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

The "best" solution I have had is to set whichever is provided, then make sure either applies to the string I need when I do my `foreach` loop like this:

```
row.WORKCENTER = row.WORKCENTER ?? row.DEPTID;
```

If I can't intercept it from the start, I guess it would be nice to apply this change to every Object in the collection instead of row by row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to create a string for the variations you expect, then reset the desired string based on the available values like this:

```
[XmlElement("MATTYPE")]
public string _Mttype { get; set; }
[XmlElement("MATLTYPE")] 
public string _Matltype { get; set; }
```

Then when using the value:

```
_Matltype = _Matltype ?? _Mttype;
```

Unfortunately, that means you will have to do that for each variation you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy solution using attributes, what if both MATTYPE and MATLTYPE are in the document ?

An quick could be:

```
[XmlElement("MATTYPE")]
public string MATTYPE { get; set; }
[XmlElement("MATLTYPE")]
public string MATLTYPE { get; set; }

public string GetMATLTYPE ()
{
    var mistakes = new string[] {MATTYPE, MATLTYPE}
    return mistakes.FirstOrDefault(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
}
```

If you want to use MATLTYPE:

```
private string _matltype;
[XmlElement("MATTYPE")]
public string MATTYPE { get; set; }
[XmlElement("MATLTYPE")]
public string MATLTYPE {
 get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_matltype) ? GetMATLTYPE() : _matltype ; }
 set { _matltype = value; }
 }
```

Comment: I need to use `MATLTYPE` as the string for the final value for other operations. How do I use the `getMATLTYPE` results to then set the `MATLTYPE` value?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working.  In fact, whenever I run in debug to see what values it is returning, it crashes when I try to look at the values.